# How to setup private docker registry securely?

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I am able to setup private docker registry insecurely and able to pull and push from remote hosts. However, i would like to change it to using secure connection. I have followed the instruction at https://docs.docker.com/articles/https/ but i am confused which steps to be followed at docker host running registry and which are to be executed at remote docker machine? Please help!!!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way is to secure your registry using nginx for SSL-termination, with a valid SSL certificate.

Here https://github.com/docker/docker-registry/tree/master/contrib/nginx  you will find sample nginx configuration to achieve that (on the registry host, obviously).

In case you can't/won't use a valid SSL certificate, you can still instruct your docker daemon hosts to either trust that certificate, or ignore cert validation errors (see here for more: https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#insecure-registries)

Hope that helps.